# надо перебрать XML внутри HTML и получить ссылку на последний <item> по дате загрузки

Tags: python, requests, rss

вот ссылка на ресурс:
https://mangalib.me/manga-rss/onepunchman
структура XML, но когда через модуль request вытаскиваю, выходит страница формата HTML и XML-а я в нем не знаю как выцепить

Comment: совершенно не понятно... html это разновидность xml.. мб попробывать модули xml.dom xml.etree

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я хочу получить данные из XML который внутри HTMLа, получить к ним доступ, чтобы с ними работать. https://mangalib.me/manga-rss/onepunchman Если request-ом парсить этот сайт парситься HTML структура, а XML внутри, то ли в функции какой, то ли еще где затарен, как ме доступ получить к элементам на странице которая выше